# Sanitize untrusted CSS using Angular $sce.getTrustedCss

Tags: css, angularjs, sanitization

Trying to use `$sce.getTrustedCss` but always am *getting an error for unsafe input.*

Should such an example be safe or am I missing something.

```
$sce.getTrustedCss('.red {color: red;}');
```

Alternatively, are there other *JS sanitizers* that can work on CSS input?
*google-caja* only works for inline styling, it removes STYLE tags altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Since Angular 2, use [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer):

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(
  private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
) {}

// let legal = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle( styleAtrStr );
```

Answer (score 0):

So far as I can tell, there is no actual CSS sanitization built in to Angular.

I think `$sce.getTrustedCss(s)` will always tell you that the input is unsafe unless you first do: `s = $sce.trustAsCss(something)`. So if you pass your css through a sanitiser, or know it came from a trusted source you can mark it as safe for use.

Note also that the Angular documentation says that Angular doesn't actually use `getTrustedCss()` but you are free to use it in your own directives. I think that means if you do use it you would be responsible for ensuring the safe inputs were first passed through `trustAsCss()`.

Here's the implementation of `getTrusted()`:

```
function getTrusted(type, maybeTrusted) {
      if (maybeTrusted === null || isUndefined(maybeTrusted) || maybeTrusted === '') {
        return maybeTrusted;
      }
      var constructor = (byType.hasOwnProperty(type) ? byType[type] : null);
      if (constructor && maybeTrusted instanceof constructor) {
        return maybeTrusted.$$unwrapTrustedValue();
      }
      // If we get here, then we may only take one of two actions.
      // 1. sanitize the value for the requested type, or
      // 2. throw an exception.
      if (type === SCE_CONTEXTS.RESOURCE_URL) {
        if (isResourceUrlAllowedByPolicy(maybeTrusted)) {
          return maybeTrusted;
        } else {
          throw $sceMinErr('insecurl',
              'Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL: {0}',
              maybeTrusted.toString());
        }
      } else if (type === SCE_CONTEXTS.HTML) {
        return htmlSanitizer(maybeTrusted);
      }
      throw $sceMinErr('unsafe', 'Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.');
    }

    return { trustAs: trustAs,
             getTrusted: getTrusted,
             valueOf: valueOf };
  }];
```

Notice that urls and html have some extra checking, but other types (css, js) are only trusted when have been wrapped by the appropriate `trustAs...` function. Also `trustAsCss()` doesn't appear to be documented, but as the shorthand methods are automatically generated it should exist (or you could use `trustAs($sce.CSS, ...)` directly).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. Any suggested alternatives for client side sanitization?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of anything to suggest.